# calling free on struct throws runtime error

Tags: c, struct, function-pointers, free

I have created a simple object system based on [Simple Object System](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex19.html).Then I decided to augment the code by adding a function to free all memory regarding the monster when it is dead:

```
void Monster_destroy(void *self)
{
    Monster* monster=self;
    if(&(monster->proto))
        free(&(monster->proto));
    free(monster);
}
```

I used the function here like this:

```
int Monster_attack(void* self,int damage)
{
    Monster* monster=self;
    char* desc=monster->proto.description;
    printf("You attack %s!\n", desc);
    monster->hit_points-=damage;
    if(monster->hit_points>0)
    {
        printf("It is still alive\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("It is dead\n");
        monster->proto.destroy(monster);
        return 1;
    }       
}
```

I get the following error:

```
==4699== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==4699==    at 0x4C2B83A: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:468)
==4699==    by 0x40080F: Monster_destroy (ex19.c:15)
==4699==    by 0x400A2C: Room_attack (ex19.c:96)
==4699==    by 0x400ACA: Map_attack (ex19.c:118)
==4699==    by 0x400E20: process_input (ex19.c:175)
==4699==    by 0x400F52: main (ex19.c:211)
==4699==  Address 0x51fd500 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 56 free'd
==4699==    at 0x4C2B83A: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:468)
==4699==    by 0x400803: Monster_destroy (ex19.c:14)
==4699==    by 0x400A2C: Room_attack (ex19.c:96)
==4699==    by 0x400ACA: Map_attack (ex19.c:118)
==4699==    by 0x400E20: process_input (ex19.c:175)
==4699==    by 0x400F52: main (ex19.c:211)
==4699==
```

I have a system where Monster looks like this:

```
struct Monster
{
    Object proto;
    int hit_points;
};

typedef struct Monster Monster;
```

`Object` is a struct that looks like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    char *description;
    int (*init)(void *self);
    void (*describe)(void* self);
    void (*destroy)(void* self);
    void* (*move)(void* self,Direction direction);
    int (*attack)(void* self,int damage);
}Object;
```

This is how I am using `Monster_destroy now:

```
 if(monster && monster->hit_points>0)
{
    monster->proto.attack(monster,damage);
    return 1;
}
else
{
           //dont even call Monster_attack because Monster has no hit_points
    printf("You flail at the air and hit nothing,Idiot\n");
    if(monster)
    monster->proto.destroy(monster);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think that this free(monster) at the end is useless because it is just a pointer on the stack (you did not allocate it on the heap).

Comment: While the answers sound correct with respect to the code you posted, I'd like to point out the fact that the call stack Valgrind shows has nothing to do with `Monster_attack`, though there is `Room_attack`. Are you sure that you've got the correct function?

Comment: Ohh wait,I changed the call of Monster_destroy from Monster_attack to Room_attack because I wanted to see if it works there instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `struct Monster` `proto` is `Object` not `Object *`.

So freeing memory like this in `Monster_destroy()` function is not valid.

```
if(&(monster->proto))
    free(&(monster->proto));
```

In fact, you haven't specifically allocated memory for `proto` so you don't need to free it.

However, if you are allocated memory for `proto->description` then you need to free it using `free(proto->description)`.

Comment: what about setting `proto` to `NULL` after freeing `description` as one answer describes above,it gives me `incompatible types when assigning to type ‘Object’ from type ‘void *’`

Answer (score 0):

In the `struct Monster`, `proto` is not dynamically allocated so you don't have to free it.

Try without the lines:

```
if(&(monster->proto))
    free(&(monster->proto));
```

in the function `Monster_destroy`.

Remember, use `free()` on a pointer only if you have used `malloc()` before on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it should be simply written like this:

```
void Monster_destroy(void *self)
{
  Monster* monster = self;
  if(&(monster->proto) != NULL)
    free(&(monster->proto));

  monster->proto = NULL;//Important
}
```

The last free you did on the monster variable is useless (at best) because you are passing an address that is located into the stack (when the function returns that address is automatically deleted by moving the sp register back).

You should use free only on dynamically allocated memory like the one you create with 'malloc' or 'new'.

Comment: As `proto` is not dynamically allocated you can't use `free()` on it. So your code is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare variables they get a memory from system stack. But when you declare pointers and allocate them memory, it gets allocated from heap. That is why you can free the memory using `free()` allocated from heap (dynamically). But you can't try to delete a memory allocated in stack using free.